# back key issue when camera started in samsung

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

```
    final Dialog dailog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());

    dailog.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog,int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                      getActivity().finish();//Line-9
            } 
    }
    });

    View dlgView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xyz, null);
    dailog.setContentView(dlgView);
    ((Button) dlgView.findViewById(R.id.button_camera)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
```

When camera get started and back key is pressed,Line-9 get also executed in some devices(like samsung s3). Is there any solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you start camera set boolean isCamaraOn = true;

and when camera is on and you press back button

then

```
 if(!isCameraOn){//go in only if camera is off
       if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                  getActivity().finish();//Line-9
        }
 }
```

here you can set isCamaraOn to false;

try this, hope works for you

Comment: Sorry, dont know about that, I am new to stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of your program is correct. Please tell us what you are trying to do(expected behavior). So that we can help you

Comment: Behavior in some devices is not correct. I have written the above code in a fragment. When I start camera from this dialog and without capturing the image, If I press back key, camera get closed and onResume() state of my Fragment get  occured . But In samsung S3, Line-9 also get executed and Activity get Finished.